# How to http stream video from a frequently updated image

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, vlc

How can I obtain an HTTP video stream from a single image file that is frequently updated (every 50ms)?

The file is on a Windows 7 machine, I can use C# but I can also send a potential stream to a linux machine.

I would try whith vlc and the fake module, but it seems not more supported. I've tried also with a pipe from ffmpeg (also over an udp localhost stream) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this FFmpeg command. It loops over a single image source and creates a live HLS stream in a directory called 'png2hls'. You can modify the rate, resolution, and quality as needed.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 30000/1001 -i image.png -an -s 960x540 -r 30000/1001 -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -maxrate 900k -b:v 900k -profile:v baseline -bufsize 1800k -pix_fmt yuv420p -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename 'png2hls/file%03d.ts' png2hls/index.m3u8
```

All option definitions should be available here.
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Hope that helps.

Ian

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need more informations, how can I deliver those files? Through a normal web server like nginx?

Comment: Great. Feel free to mark the answer as useful. As long as the 'png2hls' directory is in your web directory, you can access HLS stream via http://yourdomain.tld/.../png2hls/index.m3u8

Comment: Yes. Is this related to obtaining an HTTP video stream from a single image file?

Comment: Quite.The images were on a PC different from the web server, so the video stream were obtained through ffmpeg and send it via RTMP, then nginx-rtmp module transformed it in a HLS stream. But I realized that is more convenient to make a unique transformation from images to HLS, and install a web server on the source PC.

Comment: Sounds fine. As long as the source PC (now with a web server) is publicly accessible, people should be able to access your HLS stream. Good luck!

Comment: Can we stream also a set of images? It would be cool to stream time lapse images.